# ICorProfiler: Why do I get the wrong type token for a jitted function?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, clr-profiling-api

I have code that is structured like this:

```
class A {
    void M() {}
}
delegate void B<T1,T2>(T1 key, T2 value);
```

And I'm using the ICorProfiler2 API to profile that code. Now, when method M is jitted, I get a FunctionID* pointer to its ID. I then do the following (heavily abbreviated):

```
mdToken functionToken = mdTypeDefNil;
mdTypeDef classToken = mdTypeDefNil;
IMetaDataImport* pMDImport = NULL;
profilerInfo->GetTokenAndMetaDataFromFunction(functionId,
        IID_IMetaDataImport, (IUnknown**) &pMDImport, &functionToken);
pMDImport->GetMethodProps(functionToken, &classToken, functionName,
        sizeof(functionName), 0, &methodAttr, &sigBlob, &sigSize, NULL,
        NULL);
```

This gives me a TypeToken in the variable classToken.

I **expected** this to be the type in which M was declared in the source (a.k.a class A), but instead I receive delegate B's type token. So my question is: Am I doing something wrong or is my assumption that GetMethodProps returns the type token of M's definition type wrong?

Unfortunately, the documentation of GetMethodProps is not very helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233163(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit:**
To clarify: I know that the wrong type is returned because I generated a file that contains all type/function tokens and the names they map to. I verified these tokens with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/): they are correct. This mapping has also been tested numerous times in other applications and seems to work just fine, so I don't think this is the source of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mixing function tokens? Because it is highly suspect... is the `functionName` you receive the right one?

Comment: Haven't checked the name yet, but I'm not storing the function tokens in a field/map/array etc. and the two calls are right after each other in the code. So I don't see how I could have passed the wrong function token. I also check the HRESULT of the first call to make sure it succeeded.

Comment: How can you know then what method are you jitting? Note that delegates have methods inside... autogenerated methods. See http://goo.gl/ZWsHcO (right pane)

Comment: I have a file that contains a mapping from type/function tokens to their names for the profiled binary, so I can look up for each token what type or function it corresponds to. I'm aware of the autogenerated methods, but those have different tokens :/

Comment: That "file" sounds suspect, how could it deal with generic methods?  There will be multiple copies of M().  I'll randomly guess you are looking for ICorProfilerInfo2::GetFunctionInfo2() so you know the type arguments.

Comment: I cross-checked the file with ILSpy http://ilspy.net/. The tokens reported by my file and ILSpy match for all methods and types in question. So I think we can rule out the file as the source of the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand why you think generics should be important. The profiler API tells me the wrong type by giving me the wrong token. Generics are not involved at this point at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, noone could provide an explanation as to why this is happening. All of my investigations lead me to believe that the profiler API sometimes simply reports the wrong type for a method.

Fortunately, the method tokens are unique within the entire assembly, so we now use these + the assembly name to identify each method uniquely and ignore the type tokens completely.